# Visual Studio doesn't recognize custom components

Tags: c#, components, runtime-error

Visual Studio started to give me useless errors like this:
[Pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WM6JF.png)

Telling me that all my custom components are not declared, even if I used them so far. I click "go to the code" and this is the result:

[pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJru1.png)

After a few restarts it comes back to work again, but this is becoming really annoying. Do you guys have any idea why it started to do that?

Comment: In the future, please don't add unrelated tags. This question have nothing to do with C++. I also recommend that you refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Check you bin folder where you built code and see if there are any dlls.  These dlls need to be in the same folder as your exe.  You probably did a clean build which removed the dlls.  The copy instruction to put in the bin folder is not automatically copy the files.  You can open the csproj file in Notepad and see if you ca find out how the files are getting copied.